# Apply filter to expression or create within the dataset Reportbuilder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

Thanks to previous suggestion/help.  The expression =IIF(Count(Fields!PurOrd.Value) = Count(Fields!PurInv.Value), “Yes”, “No”) returns what I was looking for, however as the report is progressing I’m now looking to display only the “No” returns.  Is there an option to add this to the expression or can this be captured within the dataset, if so, can someone share their solution.

Select
Narrative_Note

,CASE Narrative_Note WHEN ‘PurOrd’ THEN Narrative_Note END AS ‘PurOrd’
,CASE Narrative_Note WHEN ‘PurInv’ THEN Narrative_Note END AS ‘PurInv’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your expression contains an Aggregate function (COUNT), you can only filter it in a Group FILTER. Luckily, you are already using the aggregate expression so you would just add it to the Group FILTER.

Either right-click the group indicator on the left of the table (that looks like  **(** an open parenthesis)

[image]

or, in the Grouping Window, click on your group's drop down arrow and select Group Properties.

On the Filters tab, Add a Filter with your expression for the Expression

```
=IIF(Count(Fields!PurOrd.Value) = Count(Fields!PurInv.Value), “Yes”, “No”)
```

and **No** for the value.